# How to recover my data from a full ubuntu VM?

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, data-recovery

My ubuntu virtual machine is not running because of lack of space. I tried to remove some files but it doesn't help at all and I don't want to start deleting random files. I can run the terminal if I run ubuntu in recovery mode. From that VM I just need a couple scripts(some .txt files). Everytime I try recovering my files I get some error that I don't have enough space(e.g. I can't upload my data to github because I can't install the extension). What can I do to recover those .txt files?
ubuntu version: ubuntu version 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: Save them to some other media instead of uploading to github directly?

Comment: It's really easy to add more disk space (assuming there's space on the host) to a VBox VM. Open the media section, make the size of the virtual disk image larger, boot the VM to a live ISO of your choice (F12 during boot), and 'grow' the partition with gparted.